# Remove item from DynamoDB with composite sorting key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a composite sorting key "123#abc" and I want to remove the item starting with "123".
I can query with such a prefix but I didn't find how to delete an item using a prefix.
AWS doc says I need to provide [both partition and sorting keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteItem.html#:%7E:text=For%20a%20composite%20primary%20key%2C%20you%20must%20provide%20values%20for%20both%20the%20partition%20key%20and%20the%20sort%20key.).
Is it possible to remove an item using a prefix of sort key?

I can query for exact sorting key before removal but I'm curious if delete operation supports this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately its not supported, for a singleton operations such as `DeleteItem`, `GetItem`, `PutItem` etc... you must know the entire primary key, that is Partition and Sort keys (if a sort key exists).

The only option is to read using `Query`, then loop the results and call `DeleteItem` with the keys obtained.

Comment: Probably worth batching deletes using BatchWriteItem for better performance